# Beckhoff error encountered AdsError: 1823 or(0x71f)

Tags: ads, plc, twincat

The Beckhoff PLC is stuck in config mode and when I am trying to activate configuration from my PC no error is shown in the error list but on the screen attached with PLC it is showing:
**Init12\IO: Set state TComObj SAFEOP, Set Objects(3) to SAFEOP>> AdsError 1823 (0x71f)**

There is nothing available in the documentation. The notice box is asking me to start event viewer and open application log but what am I supposed to do after that?
How to rectify this error?

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your IO device not being linked to a compatible device.
You need to change the adapter settings of the device using the device tree.

Please follow the advice in this [blog](http://soup01.com/en/2021/12/22/beckhofftwincat3-adserror-1823-0x71f-sorry-no-error-description-solution-2/)